# I can't install PYQt5 in python

Tags: installation, pip, pyqt5

I tried to install PYQt5 in python 3.8. But I received this error:

C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38>pip3 install PyQt5-5.15.9.tar
Processing c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\pyqt5-5.15.9.tar
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 2
╰─> [86 lines of output]
Collecting sip<7,>=6.6.2
Downloading sip-6.7.8-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (609 kB)
-------------------------------------- 609.1/609.1 kB 8.3 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting PyQt-builder<2,>=1.14.1
Downloading PyQt_builder-1.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.7 MB)
------------------------                 2.3/3.7 MB 13.8 kB/s eta 0:01:47
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
yield
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 561, in read
data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
data = self.__fp.read(amt)
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 458, in read
n = self.readinto(b)
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 502, in readinto
n = self.fp.readinto(b)
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
      status = run_func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
      return func(self, options, args)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 419, in run
      requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
      result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
      state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
      self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
      if not criterion.candidates:
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
      return bool(self._sequence)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
      return any(self)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
      return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
      candidate = func()
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
      self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
      super().__init__(
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
      self.dist = self._prepare()
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
      dist = self._prepare_distribution()
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
      return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
      return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 536, in _prepare_linked_requirement
      local_file = unpack_url(
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
      file = get_http_url(
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
      from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 147, in __call__
      for chunk in chunks:
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
      for chunk in iterable:
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
      for chunk in response.raw.stream(
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 622, in stream
      data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 587, in read
      raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
      raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
  pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 2
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

When I install PYQt5 with pip install PyQt5; I received this error too. Please help me. Thanks alot.

I tried these two commands:
pip install PyQt5
pip3 install PyQt5

and these two command after downloading PyQt5 from pypi website:
pip3 install PyQt5-5.15.9.tar
pip install PyQt5-5.15.9.tar

but I can't install this library.